# Sort a python array in a customized order based on it's content

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am trying to extract information from a CV and output it in the console.

In my program I get at one point an array like

```
language = ['german : bilingual', 'english : advanced', 'dutch : intermediate', 'french : bilingual']
```

and I would like to tranform it to

```
sorted= ['french : bilingual','german : bilingual', 'english : advanced', 'dutch : intermediate']
```

So from best to worst in skill and in alphabetical order after.

Is there a way to program that in python?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, define a list of words defining the skill levels, and then sort `language` according to this. Did you know that the built-in `sorted` function exists and has a `key` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a call to [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), specifying a two part key to sort by; the first part is the index of the skill part of the term in a list specifying the ordering for skills, and the second part is the language name (it's safe to sort on the whole string since the language comes first):

```
language = ['german : bilingual', 'english : advanced', 'dutch : intermediate', 'french : bilingual']
order = [ 'bilingual', 'advanced', 'intermediate' ]
lsort = sorted(language, key=lambda x:(order.index(x.split(' : ')[1]),x))
print(lsort)
```

Output:

```
['french : bilingual', 'german : bilingual', 'english : advanced', 'dutch : intermediate']
```

Comment: You do not know the ranking of the skills in this ways - how do you know that advanced> intermediate?

Comment: @Stef thanks for pointing that out, I didn't intend an index on that at all. I've corrected the code.

Comment: @CutePoison the skills are ranked according to their index in the `order` list, so `bilingual > advanced > intermediate`. My `order.index` yields exactly the same result as your `maps` dictionary.

Comment: But if you shuffled that array at the beginning, then it wouldn't work would it? I agree, if you know it is sorted in advance, it is a much cleaner solution

Comment: @CutePoison the input array is not sorted. If you mean the `order` array, why would you shuffle it? It's a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a build-in library, but should be doable like this:

First of all, you'll need to sort how the different skills are according to eachother

```
maps = {"bilingual":0,"advanced":1,"intermediate":2}
```

then we create a 2D list

```py
splits =[p.replace(" ","").split(":") for p in language] #Remove the spaces and split on ":"
```

You use `sorted` with multiple keys:

```py
sort = np.array(sorted(splits,key= lambda x: (maps[x[1]],x[0]))) #Sort first by level, then by language
```

at last create the wanted list of strings

```py
sort_str =[f"{lang} : {lvl}" for (lang,lvl) in zip(df["lang"],df["lvl"])]
```

If we combine it all

```py
import numpy as np
language = ['german : bilingual', 'english : advanced', 'dutch : intermediate', 'french : bilingual']
maps = {"bilingual":0,"advanced":1,"intermediate":2}
splits =[p.replace(" ","").split(":") for p in language]
sort = np.array(sorted(splits,key= lambda x: (maps[x[1]],x[0])))
sort =[f"{lang} : {lvl}" for (lang,lvl) in zip(sort[:,0],sort[:,1])]

sort_str
#['french : bilingual',
#'german : bilingual',
#'english : advanced',
#'dutch : intermediate']
```

Comment: This seems a little bit complicated (and hard to understand by just reading the code) for something that could be done with one single call to `sorted`.

Comment: You cannot just call sorted, since you don't know the ranking of "advanced, intermediate, bilingual" in advance. You need to create that ranking first